# Fill Jenkins Parameters with current file paths in a directory on the build machine

Tags: jenkins

Is there a dynamic way to list files on a directory as choice parameters before jenkins build starts?
I've seen a couple of plugins but I'm not quite sure if that's the way to go.

plugin 1: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in
plugin 2: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin

So basically what I have is a directory with "file1", "file2", .., "fileN"

I want to be able to list them as choice parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look to the Filesystem List Parameter plugin?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Filesystem+List+Parameter+Plug-in

It seems helpful for your problem :)

Comment: Hi Bruno,Where it will display and how to configure FileSystem List Parameter Plugin?

Comment: @RajeshOm According to the plugin site (https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin), it's in the global config.